# Laravel query with multiple 'with' statements

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm not sure if there's a a way of doing this but I would like to add a where clause to the second with in my query but it doesn't work. It just returns all the votes as if the condition wasn't there. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function PostId($request)
{
    $post_id = $request->post_id;
    $user_id = auth('api')->user();

    $post = Post::with('categories')
        ->where('id', $post_id)
        ->with('votes')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id->id)
        ->first();

    return $post;
}
```

Comment: You just put them into an array. `with(['categories', 'votes'])`

Comment: do you want to restrict the eager loading of the relationship or do you want to filter `Post` by a condition of a relationship existing?

Comment: @Second2None That's not quite correct. If you want to add a condition to your `votes` relationship, you use an array with a callback: `with(['votes' => function ($subQuery) use ($user_id) { return $subQuery->where('user_id', $user_id->id); }])`. Sidenote, `$user_id` is a bad variable name since it's the actual `User` instance, and not just the id. Change to `$user_id = auth('api')->user()->id`, or `$user = auth('api')->user()`, then `$user->id`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've updated the variable name and implemented the call-back but it's returning an empty object. No errors.

Comment: what is returning an empty object?

Comment: The new query with the updated callback as suggested by Tim.

Comment: so `$post` is an empty object? `first` returns `null` or a Model instance, so ...  you have to clarify the things you are saying

Comment: Ignore me. I've made a basic error and neglected to put get at the end of the $post query. It's working as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: as long as you get there in the end ... doc reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads ...  good luck, have fun and enjoy Laravel

Answer (score 1):

You need to use closure in your `with` statement.

Also, I'd recommend using `findOrFail()` instead of `where` conditional for your query. Therefore, in case you pass a wrong `post_id` in your request an exception 404 will be thrown.

A nicer way to accomplish what you want could be:

```
public function PostId($request)
{
    $post = Post::with(['categories', 'votes' => function($query){
           $query->where('user_id', auth('api')->user()->id);
        })
        ->findOrFail($request->post_id);

    return $post;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$post = Post::find($post_id) // Find method will return only first record. no need to call ->first() explicitly.
    ->with([
        'categories',
        'votes'
    ])
```

For the `->where('user_id', $user_id->id)`, you dont need to do it in here as you already have defined the relation 'votes'.

```
Class Post
{
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class)->where('user_id', $this->user_id); // You can have the where condition here assuming you have user id field present in the Post model. Else you can keep it as below in your query
    }
}
```

With user id in the runtime query

```
$post = Post::find($post_id)
    ->with([
        'categories',
        'votes' => function($query) use($user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id->id);
        }
    ])
```

Comment: `with` returns a eloquent builder, not a result ... `find` runs a query and returns the Model then `with` starts a new eloquent builder which would then need to execute the query eventually to do anything [you need to change the order of these 2 method calls]... and you can't add the `where` condition to the relationship method on the model itself, when eager loading a new non existing model instance is used to call the relationship method, not an existing one (it has no attributes) `$this->user_id` would be `null` in that case